# Website reverses console output

Tags: javascript

A certain website I encountered reverses the console output.
That means that whenever I try to `console.log("something")` i get `gnihtemos`

[image]

Can someone explain how this website achieves this effect?

Comment: Chrome  45.0.2454.85 doesn't do that for me.

Comment: I am using 45.0.2454.85 m and it works nice to me

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally enabled a right-to-left writing direction. There are some shortcut keys that can do this such as right-ctrl, right-shift and an arrow key together.

Comment: The most probably thing that occurs here is that your browser is configured to read text RTL (right to left) and not LTR (left to right). Check your browser's config

Comment: This seems to be strange.I tested this code withing the console.On StackOverflow and other websites it prints correctly.But on a certain website(don't know if I should post it here)when I input it in the console it prints reversed.I will edit the question to show the differences

Comment: And no, I don't have any kind of right to left configurations

Comment: i think the problem with the website NOT in Google Chrome

Comment: And i think the problem is not in LTR or RTL , because they doesn't affect the numbers
For example : 
When you use RTL method and print 15 in console log() 
it prints 15 NOT 51 :/

Comment: I changed to question to be more specific

Comment: At a guess - the website is overriding `console.log`.  You could search the js source files in chrome for `log=` or `log =` etc, you may turn up where it's doing it.

Comment: ...or `console.prototype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure. But probably the `console.log` has been overwritten in the mentioned website. As you can see in your printscreen, the printed numbers are black, but it should be blue. It means that the numbers are being converted to a `string`. You can reproduce the same effect with the code below.

```
var oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function () {

    var x = 0, 
        l = arguments.length;

    for (x; x < l; x += 1) {

        typeof arguments[x] === 'number' && (arguments[x] = arguments[x].toString());
        typeof arguments[x] === 'string' && (arguments[x] = arguments[x].split('').reverse().join(''));

    }

    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace functions anywhere, so you can do:

```
console.log = function(str){

  return str.split('').reverse().join('');

}
```

And suddenly every console log is reversed. This is a silly example, it wouldnt work for multiple arguments nor numbers.